# Gulp + browserify + babelify: "Unexpected token" for JSX code

Tags: reactjs, gulp, jsx

The code I tried to transpile is this:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var listOfItems = <ul>
                    <li className="item-1">Item 1</li>
                    <li className="item-2">Item 2</li>
                    <li className="item-3">Item 3</li>
                  </ul>;

ReactDOM.render(listOfItems, document.getElementById('react-application'));
```

The gulpfile.js looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return browserify('./source/app.js')
    .transform(babelify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('snapterest.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});
```

But if I try to start `gulp`, it gives me this error:

```
[18:00:34] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/Esercitazioni/react/reactjs-essentials/snapterest/gulpfile.js
[18:00:34] Starting 'default'...
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

SyntaxError: /Users/macbookpro/Documents/Esercitazioni/react/reactjs-essentials/snapterest/source/app.js: Unexpected token (4:18)
  2 | var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
  3 | 
> 4 | var listOfItems = <ul>
    |                   ^
  5 |                     <li className="item-1">Item 1</li>
  6 |                     <li className="item-2">Item 2</li>
  7 |                     <li className="item-3">Item 3</li>
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/macbookpro/Documents/Esercitazioni/react/reactjs-essentials/snapterest/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:22:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/macbookpro/Documents/Esercitazioni/react/reactjs-essentials/snapterest/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:91:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/Users/macbookpro/Documents/Esercitazioni/react/reactjs-essentials/snapterest/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:512:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/macbookpro/Documents/Esercitazioni/react/reactjs-essentials/snapterest/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:270:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/macbookpro/Documents/Esercitazioni/react/reactjs-essentials/snapterest/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:250:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/Users/macbookpro/Documents/Esercitazioni/react/reactjs-essentials/snapterest/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:180:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/macbookpro/Documents/Esercitazioni/react/reactjs-essentials/snapterest/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:157:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/macbookpro/Documents/Esercitazioni/react/reactjs-essentials/snapterest/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:120:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseVar (/Users/macbookpro/Documents/Esercitazioni/react/reactjs-essentials/snapterest/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:585:24)
    at Parser.pp.parseVarStatement (/Users/macbookpro/Documents/Esercitazioni/react/reactjs-essentials/snapterest/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:416:8)
```

Answer (score 6):

From the [`babelify` docs](https://github.com/babel/babelify):

> As of [Babel 6.0.0](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/29/6.0.0/) there are **no plugins included by default**. For babelify to be useful, you must also include some [presets](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets) and/or [plugins](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#transform).

In your case that means you need [`babel-preset-es2015`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015) and [`babel-preset-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react):

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react
```

Then you need to tell `babelify` to use them:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  return browserify('./source/app.js')
    .transform(babelify.configure({presets: ['es2015','react']}))
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('snapterest.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does wrapping the `<li>` in parens help?

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var listOfItems = (
              <ul>
                <li className="item-1">Item 1</li>
                <li className="item-2">Item 2</li>
                <li className="item-3">Item 3</li>
              </ul>
    );

ReactDOM.render(listOfItems, document.getElementById('react-application'));
```

Comment: If I write the same code using JavaScript code without using JSX, gulp give me no error. Only using JSX gulp give me error.

Comment: Ah, I imagine your babelify is not configured correctly to support react syntax. I'm no expert at babelify so I'm not sure how to best fix that, sorry